# Javascript array group on specific elements in for loop

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, for-loop

I currently have some code that displays some html based on a MySQL query. In my current query I am only selecting distinct rows with the `MAX(ID)` (the first item in each array element). I am looking to expand that now and my array now looks like this:

```
var fullcheckins = [["3835","101 Pub","40.8684","-74.0223"],
                    ["2182","101 Pub","40.8684","-74.0223"],
                    ["2181","101 Pub","40.8684","-74.0223"],
                    ["1574","101 Pub","40.8684","-74.0223"],
                    ["1573","101 Pub","40.8684","-74.0223"],
                    ["1572","101 Pub","40.8684","-74.0223"],
                    ["1269","101 Pub","40.8684","-74.0223"],
                    ["1230","101 Pub","40.8684","-74.0223"],
                    ["221","101 Pub","40.8684","-74.0223"],
                    ["220","101 Pub","40.8684","-74.0223"],
                    ["697","113th St. Beach, LBI","39.5938","-74.2145"],
                    ["2838","14th Star Brewery and Taproom","44.8145","-73.0817"],
                    ["2844","14th Star Brewing Co","44.8201","-73.0854"],
                    ["2842","14th Star Brewing Co","44.8201","-73.0854"],
                    ["2841","14th Star Brewing Co","44.8201","-73.0854"],
                    ["2840","14th Star Brewing Co","44.8201","-73.0854"]];
```

What I want is some way to separate each row where where each element in fullcheckins is the same and the group them together. If it helps, the array is in order. Here is what I am expecting:

```
for (var i = 0; i < checkins.length; i++) {
  var checkin = checkins[i];
  var htmlscript = '<div id="slideShowImages">'
  for each time checkin[2] is the same:
      htmlscript += '<img src="pictures/'+checkin[0]+'.jpg"/>'
  htmlscript += '</div>'
```

In the end, I should have gone through the for loop multiple times with multiple `htmlscript` variables like such:

```
  htmlscript = '<div id="slideShowImages">
                  <img src="pictures/3835.jpg"/>
                  <img src="pictures/2182.jpg"/>
                  <img src="pictures/2181.jpg"/>
                  <img src="pictures/1574.jpg"/>
                  <img src="pictures/1573.jpg"/>
                  <img src="pictures/1572.jpg"/>
                  <img src="pictures/1269.jpg"/>
                  <img src="pictures/1230.jpg"/>
                  <img src="pictures/221.jpg"/>
                  <img src="pictures/220.jpg"/>
                </div>'
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to rearrange your `fullcheckins` before rendering them. Something like:

```
var groups = fullcheckins.reduce(function (groups, checkin) {
  var groupBy = checkin[2];
  if (!groups.hasOwnProperty(groupBy)) {
    groups[groupBy] = [];
  }
  groups[groupBy].push(checkin)
  return groups
}, {})
```

You'll then get something that looks like

```
{
  40.8684: Array[10],
  39.5938: Array[1],
  44.8145: Array[1],
  44.8201: Array[4]
}
```

Comment: This might actually be quite useful. Can I do the group by on two of the elements instead of just one? Also, as stated in the question, the fullcheckins array is already ordered by checkin[1], then checkin[2], then checkin[3], followed by descending checkin[0]

Comment: You certainly can, just change the `var groupBy` line to be whatever you'd like.

For example, something like `var groupBy = checkin[2] + "," + checkin[3];` would give you keys that look like `"40.8684,-74.0223"`

Comment: I would point out that none of the available options are a perfect way of uniquely identifying a business location (which I assume is what you're trying to do). If there is any way your query can return whatever unique identifier the DB is using for the location, that's definitely the best key to use.

Comment: There is no unique identifier for location in the database unfortunately. The lat/long will always be unique in this case, so what you said will suffice. My next question is how to convert it into the html format.

Comment: I have answered my own question. This worked out wonderfully, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for.

1) first build a results object that tracks the id for each occurrence

2) now we have an object with indexes mapped to ids

3) for each of those write the appropriate html

```js
var results = {}

var fullcheckins = [
  ["3835", "101 Pub", "40.8684", "-74.0223"],
  ["2182", "101 Pub", "40.8684", "-74.0223"],
  ["2181", "101 Pub", "40.8684", "-74.0223"],
  ["1574", "101 Pub", "40.8684", "-74.0223"],
  ["1573", "101 Pub", "40.8684", "-74.0223"],
  ["1572", "101 Pub", "40.8684", "-74.0223"],
  ["1269", "101 Pub", "40.8684", "-74.0223"],
  ["1230", "101 Pub", "40.8684", "-74.0223"],
  ["221", "101 Pub", "40.8684", "-74.0223"],
  ["220", "101 Pub", "40.8684", "-74.0223"],
  ["697", "113th St. Beach, LBI", "39.5938", "-74.2145"],
  ["2838", "14th Star Brewery and Taproom", "44.8145", "-73.0817"],
  ["2844", "14th Star Brewing Co", "44.8201", "-73.0854"],
  ["2842", "14th Star Brewing Co", "44.8201", "-73.0854"],
  ["2841", "14th Star Brewing Co", "44.8201", "-73.0854"],
  ["2840", "14th Star Brewing Co", "44.8201", "-73.0854"]
];

fullcheckins.map(function(checkin) {
  var numINQuestion = checkin[2]
  results[numINQuestion] = []
  for (var i = fullcheckins.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (fullcheckins[i][2] == numINQuestion) {
      results[numINQuestion].push(fullcheckins[i][0])
    }
  };
})

for (var prop in results) {
  var htmlscript = '<div id="slideShowImages-" ' + prop + '>';
  results[prop].forEach(function(id) {
    htmlscript += '<img src="pictures/' + id + '.jpg"/>';
    htmlscript += '</div>';
  })

  $('#results').append(htmlscript)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: This seems like it would work out well. My only question is: can `numINQuestion` be based on both `checkin[2]` and `checkin[3]`? There is a chance that `checkin[2]` is not unique, but both of them combined would be.

Comment: I mean, sure... that variable is declared in the callback function passed to map. the map array method maps that callback function to every element in the array that it is called on., which in this case is an array of values /*  ["2840", "14th Star Brewing Co", "44.8201", "-73.0854"]*/ you can do whatever you please with those

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: to answer your question though, you should just check both coordinates for equality in your if statement and name the property on the results object representing the index of this place something more meaningful like locationName